# Disk Cache Not Working properly iOS

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have implemented **NSURLCache** in my AppDelegate.

```
 NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:500*1024*1024 diskCapacity:300 * 1024 * 1024 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

And i set and fetch the cache image like this

```
UIImage *cachedImage = [[UIImageView sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:urlRequest];
    [[UIImageView sharedImageCache] cacheImage:responseObject forRequest:urlRequest];
```

But each time i run the app all the images are fetched from the source.

**Am i doing something wrong here ?**

Answer (score 0):

NSURLCache won't work if the response objects are larger than 5% of the in-memory cache capacity. So in your case, I would advise to check if the response are not larger than ~26 MB unzipped.

Other than that, make sure that the server sets the correct headers which allow the caching.